# Real time update line chart data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I wanted to show live data coming from server per sec.

I have follow some real time demos but they when i try to shift old data it update entire path and that translation look weird
look for these two links

with data here http://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/j9unf09d/  ( this work good bur it saved old data that already passed so after 30 min browser crashed )

and when I shift old data  http://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/q2w6sewa/2/ ( in this version i try to remove first each time and than start ugly translation  )

line NO **557**

```
object.pushData()
```

use first **Toggle live** button on left top

feel free to play with code..

after 30 min browser kill it self because data hold too much spaces in browser that's why i must have to remove old data that are already passed

code

```
updateLines = function(islive){
        // debugger;

        barGroup.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .style("display",function(d){
                // console.log(d);
                if(d.visible){
                    return "block";
                }else{
                    return "none";
                }
            });

        bars
        .data(function (_d) {
                var _s = [];
                var _modelObj = {};
                _modelObj = _d;
                _modelObj.values = [];
                data.forEach(function(e){
                    var _obj = {};
                    if(_d.visible){
                        _obj.value = e[_d.attr];    
                    }else{
                        _obj.value = 0;
                    }

                    _obj.color = _d.color;
                    _obj.modelId = _d.id;
                    _obj.date = e.date;
                    _modelObj.values.push(_obj);
                });
                _s.push(_modelObj);
                return  _s;
            }); 


        bars.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                return d.color;
            })
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                if(d.id == "roll" || d.id == "pitch" ){
                    return priceline2(d.values);
                }
                return priceline(d.values);
            });

    }
```

now after calling this function or before if i use Data.shift();
it act like second diagram

Comment: Could you provide an example JSFiddle or StackOverflow snippet? I can't access that page due to a firewall

Comment: go for link you can get code

Comment: I can't when it's blocked by a firewall. You should also include some code in the question for it to be on-topic. Link only questions/answers aren't appropriate I'm afraid

Comment: Ok i have update two fiddle

Comment: Could you describe which translation looks weird? Is it the updating of the `d3.scale`s that happens right when you click Toggle Live? Otherwise everything seems to look good.

Comment: Look for second Diagram when we start live ...
It linear translation look like amiba effect

Comment: @XLXMXNT I have update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/q2w6sewa/2/